# How I do I solve the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$y'=y+(y)^2+1
$$
I think we have to use the Ricati equation but not sure how to approach this. Thanks,.

Comment: I don't see the dependent variable, so it should be separable.  Partial fractions?

Comment: $$\int \frac {dy}{\left ( y+\frac 12 \right )^2+\frac 34} = \int dx$$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from Wolfram Alpha at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5By%27%5Bx%5D%2F%28y%5Bx%5D%5E2%2By%5Bx%5D%2B1%29%2Cx%5D and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dy%2By%5E2%2B1

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]